# how to add a new type of questions in the survey model in odoo 16 for example a type that allows the user to upload a file, from pycharm

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-16

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <!-- Update existing survey form view -->
        <record id="view_survey_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">survey.survey.form</field>
            <field name="model">survey.survey</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="survey.survey_question_form/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                 <xpath expr="//field[@name='page_ids']/form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='question_ids']/tree/field[@name='question_type']" position="after"/>
                    <field name="file" attrs="{'invisible': [('question_type', '!=', 'survey.question.file')]}"/>
            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- Create new question type -->
        <record id="survey_question_file_type" model="survey.question.type">
            <field name="name">File Upload</field>
            <field name="code">survey.question.file</field>
            <field name="question_type">default</field>
        </record>

        <!-- Update survey template -->
        <template id="survey_survey_template" inherit_id="survey.survey_template">
            <xpath expr="//div[contains(@class, 'js_survey_question_content')]" position="after">
                <t t-if="question.question_type == 'survey.question.file'">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-form-label" for="file">File Upload</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

```
from odoo import models, fields


class SurveyQuestionFile(models.Model):
    _name = 'survey.question.file'
    _description = 'Survey Question File'
    _inherit = 'survey.question'

    file = fields.Binary(string='Uploaded File')
```

i get this error when i want to install the module that i created
The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
RPCError@http://localhost:8069/web/assets/993-37ac348/web.assets_backend.min.js:966:274
makeErrorFromResponse@http://localhost:8069/web/assets/993-37ac348/web.assets_backend.min.js:970:163
jsonrpc/promise</<@http://localhost:8069/web/assets/993-37ac348/web.assets_backend.min.js:978:34